# What are the main differences between Socialauth, Scribe-Java, and Spring Social?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-social, scribe, socialauth

I am new to OAuth, but want to find a good way to start, and use a library that has wide support

What are the benefits and disadvantages of the following (there are probably more, but these are the Java based that I have found so far)

- [Socialauth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/)
- [Scribe-Java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)
- [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social)

Comment: spring social being the part of spring wagon might have good support, but if it comes to ease of use,flexibility and light weight i will go with scribe-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For java base library you can use Socialauth because it is easy to use with any java framework like struts, spring and it provides good support to its users.

Answer (score 0):

**Socialauth** is a good choice as it provides an abstraction layer to major social login providers. 
It is also updated regularly and is adding new providers.

I tried scribe but it seems it is going to drop out support to [oAuth 2.](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Scribe-scope-revised)

Answer (score 0):

We're about to make that choice ourselves.

I've looked a the three projects on today (2020-06-05) on github:

- [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) : 5000+ stars, 1700+ forks, 14/547 open/closed issues, last commit 25 days ago on May 11, 2020
- [spring-social](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social): 586 stars, 354 forks, 67/38 open/closed issues, last commit over a year ago Apr 4, 2019
- [socialauth](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth): 248 stars, 133 forks, 21/50 open/closed issues, last commit over a year ago Apr 2, 2019

From this data it looks *clear* that [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) is the most healty of these projects...